# Receiving undefined instead of JSON

Tags: reactjs, json, api, go, axios

I am using React axios to receive the JSON (array of objects) from server (server side is written on Go, I checked via Postman, JSON is sent properly).

Here is how I get the data on client side:

```
export const getPostData = async () => {
    const URL = 'http://localhost:8083/test'
    try {
        const { data: { data }} = await axios.get(URL);
        console.log(data)
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};
```

And this is how the getPostData is called in App.js:

```
const App = () => {
  const [ posts, setPosts ] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPostData()
      .then((data) => {
        setPosts(data)
        console.log(data)
      })
  },[]);
```

The problem is I get **undefined** in browser console. I found many similar questions asked here, but I could not find the solution (the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is set when I send the JSON).

What should I learn more, where could be the problem? I would be very grateful for any help!

If this could be helpful, here is how I send the JSON in Go:

```
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "message": "Hello",
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks suspect:

```
const { data: { data }} = await axios.get(URL);
```

That tries to read a property called `data` from an object on the `data` property of the response from axios, like this without the destructuring:

```
const data = (await axios.get(URL)).data.data;
```

Your Go code doesn't look like it puts a `{"data": ___}` wrapper around what it sends, and Axios only adds *one* layer of `{data: ___}` wrapper to what it gives you in the response, not two.

If you want the object from the JSON response, remove the inner destructuring:

```
const { data } = await axios.get(URL);
```

`data` will be `{message: "Hello"}` assuming the Go code sends the JSON `{"message": "Hello"}`.

---

Separately, your JavaScript code seems to expect an array of posts, but your Go code is just sending `{"message": "Hello"}`.